# PyQt5. Выход из приложения при нажатии quit в menu bar

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, menu

Использую PyQt5. Имеется кнопка quit в приложении(в меню сверху) при ее нажатии программа, должна завершаться но так как в кнопке quit нет подкнопок то метод `triggeret.connect` не работает. Как правильно реализовать ?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QAction, qApp, QTextEdit


class MenuDemo(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Create Menu Bar
        bar = self.menuBar()

        # Create Root Menus
        file = bar.addMenu('File')
        quit = bar.addMenu('Quit')

        # Create Actions for menus

        open_action = QAction('Open', self)
        open_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')

        save_action = QAction('Save', self)
        save_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+S')

        # Add actions to Menus
        file.addAction(open_action)
        file.addAction(save_action)

        # Events

        quit.triggered.connect(self.close)
        file.triggered.connect(self.selected)

        self.setWindowTitle("Find Regulars")
        self.resize(600, 400)

        self.show()


    def selected(self, q):
        print(q.text() + ' selected')


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
menus = MenuDemo()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При помощи функции [`aboutToShow()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#aboutToShow)  можно при нажатии на кнопку меню выполнить заданную вами функцию

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QAction, qApp, QTextEdit


class MenuDemo(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        bar = self.menuBar()

        file = bar.addMenu('File')
        quit = bar.addMenu('Quit')

        open_action = QAction('Open', self)
        open_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')

        save_action = QAction('Save', self)
        save_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+S')

        file.addAction(open_action)
        file.addAction(save_action)

        quit.aboutToShow.connect(self.close)
        file.triggered.connect(self.selected)

        self.setWindowTitle("Find Regulars")
        self.resize(600, 400)

        self.show()

    def selected(self, q):
        print(q.text() + ' selected')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    menus = MenuDemo()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```